# Creating custom geometry in Scenekit

Tags: ios, scenekit

I cannot get my custom geometry to show up. When I debug it, all the variables seem to be holding the correct data, but nothing renders. I just now set it to try and render a single square composed of two triangles for a very simple test, but still no luck. I feel like I'm building the SCNGeometry wrong. After doing all my logic/loops/magic, I have the following:

```
var verts = SCNGeometrySource(vertices: meshVertices)
var norms = SCNGeometrySource(normals: normals)
var element = SCNGeometryElement(indices: triangleIndices, primitiveType: .triangles)
```

I've tried both of the following to create the SCNGeometry. Neither render anything, though showStatistics does indicate there are two triangles. Strangely when I touch the screen to try and move the camera, the triangle total jumps to 2.74K...

```
let newGeo = SCNGeometry(sources: [verts, norms], elements: [element])
```

-

```
var sources = [SCNGeometrySource]()
sources.append(verts)
sources.append(norms)
let newGeo = SCNGeometrySource(sources: sources, elements: [element])
```

I'm really not sure what to try next unless I've completely misunderstood something.

Just to confirm, this is the data I have in my variables:

```
meshVertices = ([SCNVector3])
    [0]: x = (Float) 0, y = (Float) 0, z = (Float) 0
    [1]: x = (Float) 1, y = (Float) 0, z = (Float) 0
    [2]: x = (Float) 0, y = (Float) 1, z = (Float) 0
    [3]: x = (Float) 1, y = (Float) 1, z = (Float) 0

normals = ([SCNVector3])
    [0]: x = (Float) 0, y = (Float) 0, z = (Float) 1
    [1]: x = (Float) 0, y = (Float) 0, z = (Float) 1
    [2]: x = (Float) 0, y = (Float) 0, z = (Float) 1
    [3]: x = (Float) 0, y = (Float) 0, z = (Float) 1

triangleIndices = ([Int])
    [0]: 3
    [1]: 2
    [2]: 0
    [3]: 3
    [4]: 0
    [5]: 1
```

I have no problem getting SCNPlane, SCNBox, or other stuff to render, so I don't think the problem is there. The problem seems to be in how I'm creating the geometry. I'm pretty sure my vertices, normals, and indices are correct, so I must be doing something wrong when trying to create the final SCNGeometry object composed of SCNGeometrySource and SCNGeometryElement.

Answer (score 3):

Though it may be a little bit too late. Hope this answer can help others, too.

When specifying indices, please do not use `Int` type. It seems that when using SceneKit (or maybe its is something even deeper like Metal/OpenGL? I am not sure), the `Int` type does not take into count. Please use `UInt32` or `UInt8` as indices here.

Comment: Thanks, saved me some head scratching.